# How to match two strings by word sequence in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string-matching

Need to find the string that matches most with a given string.

```
list = ['Mr. Adam Smith Junior', 'Anna Smith Jr.', 'Adam Jhon Smith', 'Smith Adam'];
str = 'Adam Smith Jr.';

// output: 'Mr. Adam Smith Junior'
```

I have tried by tokenizing words and for each of the item in list, it matches with 2tokens(Adam/Smith/Jr.). But my expected output is list[0]. So I need a solution to find the matched string by most matching word sequence.

Comment: Can you provide a 'working' example of what you have now?

Comment: Do you want the longest matching part as the decisive factor? And should that be in the same order? (so 'Smith Adam' should only match for 1 of the 2 words)

Comment: There are a lot of possible solutions, but to give a better answer, can you elaborate on what it should and should not match? (Does all of the `str` have to match or only (a part of) the beginning or end? Is 'Smith Adam' as good as 'Adam Smith'? ..etc.. )

Answer (score 0):

```
// Your code request - Updated code.
var list = ['Mr. Adam Smith Junior', 'Anna Smith Jr.', 'Adam Jhon Smith', 'Smith Adam'];
var str = 'Adam Smith Jr.';

// Updated code.
str = str.split(' ');
var i = 0, j = 0;
var matched = [];

// First loop for your `list` variable array to go through each string.
while(i < str.length){
    // Second loop for your `str` variable to match each part of string with your `list` variable's each string.    
    for(j=0;j < list.length;j++){      
        var match = new RegExp( str[i], 'g' );  
            if(list[j].match(match)){
            // Find exact match - Your code goes here.
            if(!matched.includes(list[j])){
                matched.push(list[j]);
            }

          }
        }
  i++;
}

// Your result of find the all matched values from `list` variable.
console.log(matched);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what your desired output. so I can update the code according to your request.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:
It seems like you're looking to find the most consecutive number of words. Here's the version that exactly does this:

```
    var list = ['Mr. Adam Smith Junior', 'Anna Smith Jr.', 'Adam Jhon Smith', 'Smith Adam'];
    var str = 'Adam Smith Jr.';

    /**
     * Representing a class to search and match a string in a list of strings
     * @param {string[]} data An array consists of input strings to search in
     * @param {string} query A string to search for
     */
    var TextMatcher = function(data, query) {

        this.wordsToSearch = extractWords(query);

        /** @type {any[]} */
        this.results = [];
        var $this = this;

        data.forEach(function(ele, idx) {

            var words = extractWords(ele);

            var start = findSearchStartPoint(words, $this.wordsToSearch);

            var numberOfMatches = findNumberOfMatches(words, $this.wordsToSearch, start);

            $this.results.push({
                words: words,
                wordsToSearch: $this.wordsToSearch,
                firstListMatchedIndex: start.firstListMatchedIndex,
                numberOfMatches: numberOfMatches,
                index: idx
            });
        });

        // The logic can be improved by using regular expression
        /**
         * Simply breaks down a string to its words
         * @param {string} s The input string 
         */
        function extractWords(s) {
            return (s || '').split(' ');
        }

        /**
         * @typedef {Object} SearchPoint Starting point of search
         * @property {number} startIndex - Index of `wordsToSearch` element
         * @property {number} firstListMatchedIndex - Index of `words` element
         */

        /**
         * Finds the starting point of the search. In other words, it returns the first word in `wordsToSearch`
         * that matches the first word in `words`
         * @param {string[]} words The array in which search will be done
         * @param {string[]} wordsToSearch The array of words that needs to be searched for
         * @returns {SearchPoint} Returns indices of each input array from which search should start
         */
        function findSearchStartPoint(words, wordsToSearch) {
            var startIndex = wordsToSearch.length;
            var firstListMatchedIndex = -1;
            for (var i = 0; i < wordsToSearch.length; i++) {
                firstListMatchedIndex = words.findIndex(function(w, x) {
                    return x > firstListMatchedIndex
                            && wordsToSearch[i].toLowerCase() === w.toLowerCase();
                });

                if (firstListMatchedIndex > -1) {
                    startIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return {
                startIndex: startIndex,
                firstListMatchedIndex: firstListMatchedIndex
            };
        }

        /**
         * Returns number of consecutive `wordsToSearch` elements in `words` starting
         * from `start`
         * @param {string[]} words The array in which search will be done
         * @param {string[]} wordsToSearch The array of words that needs to be searched for
         * @param {SearchPoint} start
         */
        function findNumberOfMatches(words, wordsToSearch, start) {
            var numberOfMatched = 0;
            if (start.firstListMatchedIndex > -1) {
                numberOfMatched = 1;
                for (var i = start.startIndex + 1; i < wordsToSearch.length; i++) {
                    if (wordsToSearch[i].toLowerCase() === (words[i + start.firstListMatchedIndex] || '').toLowerCase()) {
                        numberOfMatched++;            
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return numberOfMatched;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Sends a summary of how the search performed to `console`
     */
    TextMatcher.prototype.showResutls = function() {
        console.info('Words to be searched:')
        console.info(this.wordsToSearch);
        console.info('\n');

        this.results.forEach(function(r) {
            console.info(r.words);
            console.info('List item ' + r.index + ' ---- No. of words matched: ' + r.numberOfMatches
                            + (r.numberOfMatches > 0  ? ', First word matched: ' + r.words[r.firstListMatchedIndex] : ''));    
        });
        console.info('\n');
    };

    /**
     * Displays which `data` item has the most number of matched consecutive words in `console`
     */
    TextMatcher.prototype.mostMatched = function() {
        var max = Math.max(...this.results.map(function(el) {
            return el.numberOfMatches;
        }));
        return this.results.find(function(el) {
            return el.numberOfMatches === max;
        });
    };

    // Creates an instance of TextMatcher
    var search = new TextMatcher(list, str);
    // Shows results in console    
    search.showResutls();
    // Gets the most matched item in the list
    var res = search.mostMatched();
    // Shows the most matched item in console
    console.info('The phrase with the most consecutive words matched:');
    console.info('Phrase: "' + list[res.index] + '", No. of words matched: ' + res.numberOfMatches + ', Index: ' + res.index);
```

And the output will look like this:

```
//Words to be searched:
//[ 'Adam', 'Smith', 'Jr.' ]


//[ 'Mr.', 'Adam', 'Smith', 'Junior' ]
//List item 0 ---- No. of words matched: 2, First word matched: Adam
//[ 'Anna', 'Smith', 'Jr.' ]
//List item 1 ---- No. of words matched: 1, First word matched: Smith
//[ 'Adam', 'Jhon', 'Smith' ]
//List item 2 ---- No. of words matched: 1, First word matched: Adam
//[ 'Smith', 'Adam' ]
//List item 3 ---- No. of words matched: 1, First word matched: Adam


//The phrase with the most consecutive words matched:
//Phrase: "Mr. Adam Smith Junior", No. of words matched: 2, Index: 0
```

Please let me know if this is not still what you wanted.

==================================

INITIAL POST:

I was wondering if you're looking for something like this:

```
var list = ['Mr. Adam Smith Junior', 'Anna Smith Jr.', 'Adam Jhon Smith', 'Smith Adam'];
var str = 'Adam Smith Jr.';

// This loop finds the best matching string in the array and
// and prints it in the console
function findBestMatch(arr, s) {
    for (var i = s.length; i > 1; i--) {
        var found = arr.find(function(ele) {
            return ele.indexOf(s.substr(0, i)) > -1;
        }) || [];
        if (found.length) {
            console.info(found);
            break;
        }
    }
}

findBestMatch(list, str);
```